# Catch error for broken MapBox file (.mbtiles)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mapbox

I have a problem with catching exception for broken .mbtiles file, which need for MapBox. If file broken, when initializing MapBox view:

```
self.mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame andTilesource:self.tilesStandard];
```

I get error:
Unknown error calling sqlite3_step (11: database disk image is malformed) rs

What can I do to catch this error?

**Update:** I solved the problem by using SQLite libraries directly to open the MBTiles to test it, as suggested **incanus**:

```
- (BOOL)isReadableDatabase:(sqlite3 *)database {
   BOOL result = YES;
   sqlite3_stmt* statement;
   char * errmsg;
   NSString *query = @"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=\'table\'";

   if ( sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query.UTF8String, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK ) {

      while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW ) {
         NSString *tableName = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSString *query_table = format(@"SELECT * FROM %@", tableName);

         if (sqlite3_exec(database, query_table.UTF8String, NULL, NULL, &errmsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
            DLog(@"The map is corrupted with sql error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database))
            sqlite3_close(database);
            result = NO;
            break;
         }
      }
}

   sqlite3_clear_bindings(statement);
   sqlite3_finalize(statement);

   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you try to use FMDB or SQLite libraries directly to open the MBTiles to test things first. Both should have calls that let you determine if things were successful or not before you pass them to a higher-level library.